# RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH - no activity found to handle it on emulator

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying speech recognition feature on android emulator but when I try to launch recognizer intent on my emulator with 2.1, no activity is present. Why is it not available out of the box? Is it normal? Is it possible to install support?

Thanks

Comment: What is the device that is giving you this error?

Comment: Eclair 2.1 with google API 7. I have not even any type of voice search enabled. Thanks Commonsware for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: "Eclair 2.1 with google API 7" is not a device. A device is a phone.

Comment: I have not tried it on a phone. I am complaining about the impossibility to try my program on the emulator. I have a device with no support since it has android 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that emulator has not Speech Recognition feature yet. To solve partially the problem it is possible to download the system image from http://developer.htc.com/adp.html and substitute it to android 1.6 system.img of the emulator. This makes speech recognition enable.